# How to send GET request (for login) from Angular to Laravel

Tags: angular, rest

I have an API link on Laravel as: `http://localhost:8081/api/login` with JSON parameters:

```
{
  user: "",
  password: ""
}
```

Worked great on Postman, so how can I make a request from Angular (I have a login form from `formdata`).

Answer (score 0):

According to the Standards GET requests should not have body. Due to that Angular HttpClient Module don't support body for GET requests. Instead it is recommended to use POST request for your Login Functionality.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:8081/api/login', {
 user: "",
 password: ""
 }).subscribe(data => {
})
```

I suggest you to give URL through env variables.